# How to structure my thesis

Tags: bibtex, texmaker, include

I am currently writing my BSc thesis and want to use LaTeX. I am using Texmaker on Windows and have several problems that occured. I want to use BibTeX for my literature and *\bibliographystyle{humanbio}* as style. I further want to include the different sections by the *\input{}* command. A minimal would look like this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{humanbio}
\usepackage{multibib}

\begin{document}

\title{WORKING: \\Title}
\author{ABC\\BLUB}
\publishers{Supervised by:  XYZ}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\vspace{-1cm}
\input{introduction.tex}
\bibliography{biblio,webbib}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, I do not see the references and Texmaker shows an error message:

```
Process started

The 8-bit codepage and sorting file: 88591lat.csf The top-level auxiliary file: bachelor_thesis.aux The style file: humanbio.bst I found no \citation commands---while reading file bachelor_thesis.aux Database file #1: biblio.bib Database file #2: webbib.bib (There was 1 error message)

Process exited with error(s)
```

EDIT: How can I get it, so that it shows all the references and not just the ones used?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\nocite{*}`…

Comment: Welcome to  TeX SX! Did you run tne  normal cycle `LaTeX >bibtex > LaTeX (twice)`? Also, to have all bibliographical references, whether cited or not, add `\nocite{*}`.